# node-v12.16.1.pkg” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: node.js, macos

**"node-v12.16.1.pkg” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.**

I have try to install node.js on Mac it show an error message, 
now I have change the privacy and security settings
select allow Appstore downloads to installation working fine.
not select allow App Store and identifier

Answer (score 3):

now I have  click the privacy and security settings, to tap general then 
select allow Appstore downloads to installation it's working fine.
not select allow App Store and identifier